# Memory problems with rasterbricks on cluster

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

```
    #load a .nc file
    temp=brick(temp.nc)
temp
temp
class       : RasterBrick
dimensions  : 180, 360, 64800, 2928  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 360, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84
data source : /fhgfs/data/work/crct/bfb16057/pgf/1.0deg/3hourly/tas_3hourly_1948-1948.nc
names       : X1948.01.01.00.00.00, X1948.01.01.03.00.00, X1948.01.01.06.00.00, X1948.01.01.09.00.00, X1948.01.01.12.00.00, X1948.01.01.15.00.00, X1948.01.01.18.00.00, X1948.01.01.21.00.00, X1948.01.02.00.00.00, X1948.01.02.03.00.00, X1948.01.02.06.00.00, X1948.01.02.09.00.00, X1948.01.02.12.00.00, X1948.01.02.15.00.00, X1948.01.02.18.00.00, ...
Date/time   : 1948-01-01 00:00:00, 1948-12-31 21:00:00 (min, max)
varname     : tas
level       : 1
```

I am working with large netcdf files on a cluster with package raster. First I had problems with some custom functions so I had to rewrite them and use getValues and setValues to perform calculations on these rasterBricks, that solved the problem.

But now when I call reclassify inside the main script

```
reclasstemp=reclassify(temp,rcl)
```

R crashes. Everything works if I run it on my local machine. Is there a workaround for this or a solution?

> Error in matrix(unlist(ini), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) :   'data' must
>   be of a vector type, was 'NULL' Calls: reclassify ...
>   .rasterObjectFromFile -> .rasterFromRasterFile -> readIniFile ->
>   matrix In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to
>   see the first 50)

I can't use reclassify with get/setValues because reclassify expects a raster, so that won't work. Otherwise I will have to reclassify the matrices in `v=getValues(temp)`

```
> str(v)
 num [1:64800, 1:2928] 222 222 222 222 221 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2928] "X1948.01.01.00.00.00" "X1948.01.01.03.00.00" "X1948.01.01.06.00.00" "X1948.01.01.09.00.00" ...
```

Comment: you are not providing sufficient information. Have you looked at `raster::clusterR` ?

Comment: @RobertH I should look into that. What other information could be useful to troubleshoot this? I had to use getValues and then use temp[temp>1]=1, etc to reclassify

Comment: @RobertH It seems that setting rasterOptions(maxmemory = 1e+11) fixes the problem, clusterR might speed up the calculations but I don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: And clusterR makes the script crash, go figure. Error in serialize(data, node$con) : error writing to connection
Calls: clusterR ... postNode -> sendData -> sendData.SOCKnode -> serialize
Execution halted